# html tags in app.config file in .net console application

Tags: c#

I need to add html tags in app.config file in C# console application. I tried

```
&lt;p&gt;
```

but it dint work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

First, add a reference to `System.Web` to your project. Then, you can store your HTML by [HTML encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_encoding) it.  Simply call `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` on your value stored in the config file.

Your config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="HTML" value="&lt;p&gt;My paragraph&lt;/p&gt;"/>
</appSettings>
```

Your code:

```
string html = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HTML"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you would actually want to

string html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HTML"]);

Answer (score 0):

If its ok you can create a separate HTML file and read the content using C# code.
Then use that variable for your code.

Like below

string htmdata =  File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Sendmail\email.html");